# How to access a Set within a Set

Tags: java

I have a class State which has a Set of Arcs. (Arc is another class). Now the Lexicon class has Set of States. How do I select the State where a particular Arc is present.

```
public class State {
private static long count = 0;
private long StateNo;
private Set<Arc> arcs;
}

public class Arc {
private char charecter;
private State destState;
private Set<String> letters;
}
```

These are the classes I am refferring to.

Comment: You'll probably get more useful answers if your question is more specific.  "I tried X but it didn't work..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Lexicon has

```
private Set<State> states
```

You'll need to properly implement the equals method on the Arc class, and then loop through each state in the Lexicon class. From there you can use

```
state.getArcs().contains(targetArc)
```

to find the state that has the arc that you're after.